# Why Did I Get a Rebalancing Error When Adding New Forest

Tags: marklogic

I have a large forest that I want to split in two. So I created a new forest, then attached it to the same database as the first one, and I saw that rebalancing had begun (using the default "Bucket" approach), but eventually I noticed that it had stopped moving documents to the new forest. When I checked in the Admin UI, I saw this message...

There is currently an **XDMP-FORESTERR**:

> Error in rebalance of forest ESI-EDGAR: XDMP-JNLTXNFULL: The journal has exceeded its limit for in-process transaction records: txn_size=46.813MB, current_size=0MB, limit=42.625MB exception. Information on this page may be missing.

Any ideas on how to get around this? And why it happened in the first place? I have plenty of disk space, so that it not the problem.

Answer (score 1):

If you look at Monitoring History, how does your resource utilization look? Are you pushing the limits on CPU, Memory, or IO?

**Try increasing the journal size, and/or maybe lower the throttle on the rebalancer.**

The smaller the number for rebalancer throttle, the slower it will go. That may provide enough time to in-flight transactions to commit and complete, and avoid exceeding the journal limit.

https://docs.marklogic.com/messages/XDMP-en/XDMP-JNLTXNFULL

> ## **Message Text**
>
> The journal has exceeded its limit for in-process transaction records: txn_size=variable1MB, current_size=variable2MB, limit=variable3MB
>
> ## **Cause**
>
> A fixed limit of 1/16th of the journal size is a maximum for information about prepared uncommitted transactions. This size limit has been exceeded by the transaction being committed. No more transactions will be allowed to move to being prepared, until the transactions currently using this space have committed or rolled back successfully.
>
> ## **Response**
>
> Explicitly commit or rollback XA transactions waiting in a prepared state. Increase your journal size to allow more space for prepared uncommitted transactions.

Comment: throttling back made no difference.

I increased the journal size from 625 to 999 megabytes, but I got the error again. I am not sure how the journal size relates to the numbers in the error message...

txn_size=46.811MB, current_size=0MB, limit=42.625MB

Do I just keep raising the journal size until it works?

I have to admit I am surprised by the problem. I thought MarkLogic rebalancnig was a solid, well tested technology that would either not encounter such a problem, or would adjust to it automatically, maybe by reducing the size of each batch of files to move.

Comment: Hard to tell from symptoms, are there any extremely large docs in the DB (maybe when moving batches of large docs it is blowing out limits)? f the issue is a pocket of really large docs, there might be some ways around - such as running a CoRB job to select random docs and re-insert with node-replace. But it still might be worth opening a MarkLogic Support ticket.

Comment: There are approx. 100 XML files that are large or very large, so I suspect you are right about that. Some of them are fragments but others are not. I am wondering if the solution is to use the strategy that moves fragments instead of documents, and to fragment the ones that are not already fragmented then try again.